# Swift: Authentication for REST Call to Wordpress

Tags: swift, wordpress, rest

i'm still a bit new to swift, wordpress and REST calls, but i have to make an app that gets the posts from our wordpress site. If possible i would like to avoid using libraries. The page requires a login. I assume, i need URLRequest for that.

so far i have

```
let session = URLSession(configuration: .ephemeral, delegate: nil, delegateQueue: OperationQueue.main)
let url = URL(string: "http://mywordpresspage.net")!
let request = URLRequest(url: url)
let task = session.dataTask(with: request, completionHandler: { (data: Data?, response: URLResponse?, error: Error?) -> Void in
    guard let data = data else {
        completion(nil)
        return
    }
    //...
})
task.resume()
```

how do i add username and password to the request? My guess is, that i need to call `request.addValue()` somehow. Can anyone help me?

Answer (score 0):

You will have to use the correct URLs, i. e. the documented WordPress REST API *endpoints*. Please have a look at the [API reference](https://developer.wordpress.org/rest-api/reference/).

Comment: Do i just have to add /wp/v2/posts to the url? and how do i use the login data?